# How do I calculate the co-occurrence in the table?

Tags: r

I have a simple matrix, e.g.

```
test <- matrix(c("u1","p1","u1","p2","u2","p2","u2",
                 "p3","u3","p1","u4","p2","u5","p1",
                 "u5","p3","u6","p3","u7","p4","u7",
                 "p3","u8","p1","u9","p4"),
               ncol=2,byrow=TRUE) 
colnames(test) <- c("user","product")
test1<-as.data.frame(test)
```

test:

```
   user   product
1  u1      p1
2  u1      p2
3  u2      p2 
4  u2      p3
5  u3      p1
6  u4      p2
7  u5      p1
8  u5      p3
9  u6      p3
10 u7      p4
11 u7      p3
12 u8      p1
13 u9      p4
```

I want to count how many users bought product pair together, such as p1&p2, p2& p3...

`table(test1$product,test1$product)` give me this :

```
     p1   p2  p3  p4
 p1   4   0   0   0
 p2   0   3   0   0
 p3   0   0   4   0
 p4   0   0   0   2
```

How can I get the right result as :

```
     p1   p2  p3  p4
 p1   4   1   1   0
 p2   1   3   1   0
 p3   1   1   4   1
 p4   0   0   1   2
```

Comment: Note that you currently don't even use the username as input.

Comment: And if u1 has bought p1, p2, and p3 you want to add 1 to all of (p1,p2), (p2,p3), and (p3,p1) (plus the mirror elements)? The alternative is to have a 3-d matrix...

Comment: yes, will add 1 to all the pairs

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looking at your desired output, you are looking for the `crossprod` function:

```
crossprod(table(test1))
#        product
# product p1 p2 p3 p4
#      p1  4  1  1  0
#      p2  1  3  1  0
#      p3  1  1  4  1
#      p4  0  0  1  2
```

This is the same as `crossprod(table(test1$user, test1$product))` (reflecting Dennis's comment).

Answer (score 4):

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43631179/compute-covariance-matrix-from-list-of-occurrences/43631225#43631225) tagged to this post requested an efficient solution, but got <s>deleted</s> undeleted now.  We decided to post the solution here.

Here is one with `RcppEigen` to do the crossproduct

```
library(RcppEigen)
library(inline)
prodFun <- '
        typedef Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXi> MapMti;
        const MapMti B(as<MapMti>(BB));
        const MapMti C(as<MapMti>(CC));
        return List::create(B.adjoint() * C);
        '

funCPr <- cxxfunction(signature(BB= "matrix", CC = "matrix"),
                     prodFun, plugin = "RcppEigen") 
tbl <- table(test1)
funCPr(tbl, tbl)[[1]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    4    1    1    0
#[2,]    1    3    1    0
#[3,]    1    1    4    1
#[4,]    0    0    1    2
```

#### Benchmarks

```
set.seed(24)
test2 <- data.frame(user = sample(1:5000, 1e6, replace=TRUE),
    product = sample(paste0("p", 1:50), 1e6, replace = TRUE),
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
tbl1 <- table(test2)

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(cPP = funCPr(tbl1, tbl1)[[1]], 
              CrossP = crossprod(tbl1),
              adjMat = adjmat(tbl1)$adjacency,
              unit = "relative", times = 10L)
#Unit: relative
#   expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval cld
#    cPP 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000  1.000000    10  a 
# CrossP 2.079867 2.070509 2.234376 2.074388 2.290516  2.676798    10  a 
# adjMat 6.223034 6.500791 9.619088 7.197824 7.771270 31.394812    10   b
```

NOTE: This could be made more efficient by doing the `table` in `Rcpp`

Answer (score 3):

Ananda's solution is superior (it is lighter weight and requires no external package) but I am putting down another.  I believe this is called an **adjacency matrix** (smarter people feel free to edit this if I'm wrong):

```
library(qdap)
adjmat(table(test1))$adjacency

##        product
## product p1 p2 p3 p4
##      p1  4  1  1  0
##      p2  1  3  1  0
##      p3  1  1  4  1
##      p4  0  0  1  2
```