# Most efficient way for looping over 1.5k rows and updating a dataframe

Tags: r, performance, dataframe, processing-efficiency

I'm starting with a dataframe `f` of 1.5kk rows and trying to update an nxn dataframe `Channels` based on that `f` dataframe. So far I've got 2 `for-loops` that's leading to a very slow run of the script.

I have a table with user ids and channels they like most (you can think of it as genres of songs they like most) like below:

```
id_user | id_channel
--------------------
   1    |     43
   1    |     61
   1    |    101
   2    |     43
   2    |    631
  ..    |     ..
```

What I expect to get is a dataframe `Channels` with columns and rows like below:

```
              id channel
     |  43    61    101   631
---------------------------------
43   |  NA     6     31     9
61   |   3    NA     11     1
101  |   2     1     NA    23
631  |  10     2      3    NA
```

where I have `id_channel` in both x and y-axis. It means that there are 6 users that likes channel 43 that also likes channel 61, 1 user that likes channel 101 that also likes channel 61 and so on.

What I've done is in the code below. It works, but since my original table has 1.5kk rows, it's taking about 25 hours to the code get to its end. I assume there might be a much more eficient way to do this. `f` is the original data with 1.5kk rows (as dataframe), `lst_users` (length 650k rows) and `lst_channel` (length 50 rows) are vectors with distinct `id_users` and `id_channels`.

Basically, I subset the original table by `id_user` and then for each one of them I loop over its liked channels updating the dataframe `Channels`.

```
for (user in lst_users) {
  sub <- f[f$id_user == user,]

  for (j in 1:nrow(sub)) {
    rindex <- which(lst_channels == sub$id_channel[j])
    cindex <- which(lst_channels == unique(sub$id_channel[-j]))

    Channels[rindex, cindex] <- Channels[rindex, cindex] + 1
  }

}
```

The `Channels` dataframe is initialized like below (NAs in its diagonal and 0s for the rest of the matrix):

```
Channels <- diag(NA, nrow= length(lst_channels), ncol= length(lst_channels))
```

I'm trying to come up with a solution using functions like apply, mapply, sapply, .., but couldn't come with something that actually works. Any ideas on how to approach this problem?

**Edit:**

As [@alexis_laz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2414948/alexis-laz) pointed out there is a similar problem in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977596/how-do-i-calculate-the-co-occurrence-in-the-table/19977766) whose solution can be implemented in here.

Solution: `crossprod(table(f))`

Comment: Awesome, thanks for pointing out. I'll post later how it performed in comparison with the current implementation.

Comment: @alexis_laz, definitely a duplicate question, your link provides the perfect answer for this problem of adjacency tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Benchmarking the solution `Channels <- crossprod(table(f))` gives the following results:

```
Unit: seconds
                           expr      min       lq  median       uq      max neval
 crossprod(table(f[, c(1, 3)])) 6.059346 6.219557 6.31133 6.471866 7.358821    50
```

Light times faster than doing with 2 `for-loops` that was taking 25 hours +.