# Compute covariance matrix from list of occurrences

Tags: r, covariance

I have the following data frame:

```
# my_data
id  cg
1   a
2   b
3   a
3   b
4   b
4   c
5   b
5   c
5   d
6   d
```

I would like to compute the covariance of the values of `cg`. I believe I can obtain it by using `cov()` on the following matrix, where every cell counts the number of co-occurrences between two values of `cg`.

```
# my_matrix
cg  a  b  c  d
a   2  1  0  0
b   1  4  2  1
c   0  2  2  1
d   0  1  1  2
```

What is the quickest way to go from `my_data` to `my_matrix`? Please be aware that `cg` contains more than 700 unique values.

If there is a better way to generate the covariance matrix, I am also interested in that.

Here is the code to generate `my_data`:

```
my_data <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L),
                          cg = c("a", "b", "a", "b", "b", "c", "b", "c", "d", "d")),
                     .Names = c("id", "cg"),
                     class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: I prepared a solution and posted it on the dupe link as this was deleted earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `crossprod` with `table`

```
crossprod(table(my_data))
#    cg
#cg  a b c d
#  a 2 1 0 0
#  b 1 4 2 1
#  c 0 2 2 1
#  d 0 1 1 2
```

Comment: Your solution worked. Thank you. But I now edited the original question in a way that this solution is no longer applicable.

Comment: @Michele Please post that as a new question as the answer was based on your original post.

Comment: Ok. The new question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43639805/compute-mean-jaccard-distance-between-elements-in-a-list

Comment: @Michele Thanks, I will check it out