# Cross comparison of columns of the same data.frame

Tags: r

I have a data.frame that looks like this:

```
> DF1      

 A    B    C    D    E     
 a    x    c    h    p 
 c    d    q    t    w
 s    e    r    p    a
 w    l    t    s    i
 p    i    y    a    f
```

I would like to compare each column of my data.frame with the remaining columns in order to count the number of common elements. For example, I would like to compare column A with all the remaining columns (B, C, D, E) and count the common entities in this way:

A versus the remaining:

- A vs B: 0 (because they have 0 common elements)
- A vs C: 1 (c in common)
- A vs D: 2 (p and s in common)
- A vs E: 3 (p,w,a, in common)

Then the same: B versus C,D,E columns and so on.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can loop through the column names and compare with the other columns, by taking the `intersect` and get the `length`

```
sapply(names(DF1), function(x) {
    x1 <- lengths(Map(intersect, DF1[setdiff(names(DF1), x)], DF1[x]))
    c(x1, setNames(0, setdiff(names(DF1), names(x1))))[names(DF1)]})
#  A B C D E
#A 0 0 1 3 3
#B 0 0 0 0 1
#C 1 0 0 1 0
#D 3 0 1 0 2 
#E 3 1 0 2 0
```

---

Or this can be done more compactly by taking the cross product after getting the frequency of the long formatted (`melt`) dataset

```
library(reshape2)
tcrossprod(table(melt(as.matrix(DF1))[-1])) * !diag(5)
#    Var2
#Var2 A B C D E
#   A 0 0 1 3 3
#   B 0 0 0 0 1
#   C 1 0 0 1 0
#   D 3 0 1 0 2
#   E 3 1 0 2 0
```

NOTE: The `crossprod` part is also implemented with `RcppEigen` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977596/how-do-i-calculate-the-co-occurrence-in-the-table/43634974#43634974) which would make this faster

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use `combn` twice, once to get the column combinations and next to find the lengths of the element intersections.

`cbind.data.frame` returns a data.frame and `setNames` is used to add column names.

```
setNames(cbind.data.frame(t(combn(names(df), 2)),
                 combn(names(df), 2, function(x) length(intersect(df[, x[1]], df[, x[2]])))),
         c("col1", "col2", "count"))
   col1 col2 count
1     A    B     0
2     A    C     1
3     A    D     3
4     A    E     3
5     B    C     0
6     B    D     0
7     B    E     1
8     C    D     1
9     C    E     0
10    D    E     2
```