# How to create relational matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix, reshape

Original data:

```
df <- structure(list(ID_client = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("1_", "2_", "3_", "4_"), class = "factor"), Connected = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Year = c(2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Original data:

```
`ID_client Connected  Year
1_            1      2010
2_            1      2010
3_            1      2010
4_            0      2010
1_            1      2015
2_            0      2015
3_            1      2015
4_            0      2015`
```

My intention is to create the following data:

```
`Year ID_client    1_   2_   3_   4_
2010     1_       0    1    1    0
2010     2_       1    0    1    0
2010     3_       1    1    0    0
2010     4_       0    0    0    0
2015     1_       0    0    1    0
2015     2_       0    0    0    0
2015     3_       1    0    0    0
2015     4_       0    0    0    0`
```

In other words, a matrix that express that in, for instance, 2010 clients 1_, 2_, and 3_ were connected, while the other one was not. Importantly, I do not consider someone to be connected with herself.

I have tried the following code:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Year, Connected) %>%
  mutate(temp = rev(ID_client)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = ID_client, 
          values_from = Connected, 
          values_fill = list(Connected = 0)) %>%
  arrange(Year, temp)
```

This code does not reproduce what I need. Instead, this is the result:

```
`Year ID_client    1_   2_   3_   4_
2010     1_       0    0    1    0
2010     2_       0    1    0    0
2010     3_       1    0    0    0
2010     4_       0    0    0    0
2015     1_       0    0    1    0
2015     2_       0    0    0    0
2015     3_       1    0    0    0
2015     4_       0    0    0    0`
```

Comment: What have you already tried? Please show some code, and create a [minimal, reproducible and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It's something like a co-occurrence table - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977596/how-do-i-calculate-the-co-occurrence-in-the-table - but within each year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `group_by` `Year` and create a new column with `ID_client` values which has `Connected == 1` in each group except for the current value. We `complete` the missing levels and then cast the data to wide format.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  mutate(temp = map(ID_client, ~setdiff(ID_client[Connected == 1], .x))) %>%
  unnest(cols = temp) %>%
  complete(temp = unique(ID_client), fill = list(Connected = 0)) %>%
  mutate(ID_client  = coalesce(as.character(ID_client), temp)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = temp, 
              values_from = Connected, 
              values_fill = list(Connected = 0)) %>%
  arrange(Year, ID_client)

#   Year ID_client  `1_`  `2_`  `3_`  `4_`
#  <int> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1  2010 1_            0     1     1     0
#2  2010 2_            1     0     1     0
#3  2010 3_            1     1     0     0
#4  2010 4_            0     0     0     0
#5  2015 1_            0     0     1     0
#6  2015 2_            0     0     0     0
#7  2015 3_            1     0     0     0
#8  2015 4_            0     0     0     0
```

Comment: I do not think your code is reproducing what I wanted to do.
When Client_ID is 1_, the column "1_" received the value 1. Instead, it should have been the column "2_".

Comment: The issue with your answer is that it is dependent on this particular toy data. For instance, if the new data is df <- structure(list(ID_client = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
                                             3L, 4L), .Label = c("1_", "2_", "3_", "4_"), class = "factor"), 
                     Connected = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Year = c(2010L, 
                                                                             2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L)), class = "data.frame", 
                row.names = c(NA, -8L)) instead, it does not work.

Comment: @Miranda ok..I get it now. I had misunderstood the question earlier. I have updated the answer. Can you check if it works now ?

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a self-join, i.e. an inner join of the data to itself. Join by the pieces of information that mark off a combination of clients: this would be the values in `Year` and `Connected`. Since your desired output has zeroes on its diagonal, filter to remove cases where the two IDs are the same.

As you can see, I haven't yet transitioned to the `pivot_wider` version of `tidyr`, but this should be adaptable. In `spread`, specify that unused factor levels shouldn't be dropped so you don't lose the ID 4.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

inner_join(df, df, by = c("Year", "Connected")) %>%
  filter(Connected == 1, ID_client.x != ID_client.y) %>%
  spread(key = ID_client.y, value = Connected, fill = 0, drop = F) %>%
  arrange(Year) 
#>   ID_client.x Year 1_ 2_ 3_ 4_
#> 1          1_ 2010  0  1  1  0
#> 2          2_ 2010  1  0  1  0
#> 3          3_ 2010  1  1  0  0
#> 4          4_ 2010  0  0  0  0
#> 5          1_ 2015  0  0  1  0
#> 6          2_ 2015  0  0  0  0
#> 7          3_ 2015  1  0  0  0
#> 8          4_ 2015  0  0  0  0
```