# Calculating agreement rates, matching vectors by elements in matrix

Tags: r, for-loop

I have the following 6x10 matrix, where the rows are members of parliament and the columns are issues they voted on.

```
> print(a)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0     1
[2,]   NA    1    1    0    0    1    1    1    0     0
[3,]    0    0    0   NA    1   NA    0    1    1     1
[4,]    0    1    1   NA    0    1    1    1    1     0
[5,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    1    1    0    NA
[6,]    1    1    0    0    1    1    1    0    0    NA
```

I am trying to write a for loop that would produce a matrix containing the agreement rates between each pair of members of parliament i and j. The agreement rate is calculated as the number of issues on which i and j agreed, divided by the number of issues on which i and j voted.

The code below seems to work when I run it on 2nd and 3rd rows, does not work on 5th and 6th rows (NA's in the same element position) and gives an error when it is run in the loop:
"Error in b[j, i] <- length(which(a[i, ] == a[j, ]))/ifelse(which(is.na(a[i,  :
replacement has length zero"

How can I fix the error? If someone could suggest a more efficient way of calculating the agreement rate, that would be greatly appreciated!

```
b <- matrix(nrow=6, ncol=6)

for (i in 1:nrow(a)) {
  for (j in 1:nrow(a)) {
    b[j, i] <- length(which(a[i,] == a[j,]))/
      ifelse(which(is.na(a[i,])) %in% which(is.na(a[j,]))==0,
             length(a[i,]) - (length(which(is.na(a[i,]))) + length(which(is.na(a[j,])))),
             length(a[i,]) - (length(which(is.na(a[i,])) %in% which(is.na(a[j,]))) +
               length(!(which(is.na(a[i,])) %in% which(is.na(a[j,]))))) +
               length(!(which(is.na(a[j,])) %in% which(is.na(a[i,])))))
      }
}
```

The result should look like this:

```
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]
[1,] 1.0000000 0.5555556 0.5000000 0.3333333 0.6666667 0.6666667
[2,] 0.5555556 1.0000000 0.1428571 0.8750000 0.5000000 0.6250000
[3,] 0.5000000 0.1428571 1.0000000 0.3750000 0.5714286 0.2857143
[4,] 0.3333333 0.8750000 0.3750000 1.0000000 0.5000000 0.3750000
[5,] 0.6666667 0.5000000 0.5714286 0.5000000 1.0000000 0.3333333
[6,] 0.6666667 0.6250000 0.4285714 0.3750000 0.3333333 1.0000000
```

Calculated by hand:

```
result<- matrix(nrow=6, ncol=6, c(1, 5/9, 4/8, 3/9, 6/9, 6/9,
                                5/9, 1, 1/7, 7/8, 4/8, 5/8,
                                4/8, 1/7, 1, 3/8, 4/7, 3/7,
                                3/9, 7/8, 3/8, 1, 4/8, 3/8,
                                6/9, 4/8, 4/7, 4/8, 1, 3/9,
                                6/9, 5/8, 2/7, 3/8, 3/9, 1))
```

Comment: I'm not sure what result you want, but maybe a cross-product does it - `crossprod(replace(mat, is.na(mat), 0))` ?

Comment: Previous related discussion here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977596/how-do-i-calculate-the-co-occurrence-in-the-table

Comment: The result should be a symmetric 6x6 matrix with values ranging between 0 and 1, 1's on the diagonal.

Comment: I'm absolutely stumped on calculating the denominator in any simple fashion, but I think I can get the numerator with `tcp <- function(x) tcrossprod(replace(x, is.na(x), 0)); tcp(mat) + tcp(!mat)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try `combn` like below

```
b <- diag(nrow(a))
b[lower.tri(b)] <- combn(nrow(a),2,FUN = function(k) {v <- colSums(a[k,]);sum(v%%2==0,na.rm = TRUE)/sum(!is.na(v))})
b[upper.tri(b)] <- t(b)[upper.tri(b)]
```

which gives

```
> b
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]
[1,] 1.0000000 0.5555556 0.5000000 0.4444444 0.6666667 0.6666667
[2,] 0.5555556 1.0000000 0.1428571 0.8750000 0.5000000 0.6250000
[3,] 0.5000000 0.1428571 1.0000000 0.3750000 0.5714286 0.2857143
[4,] 0.4444444 0.8750000 0.3750000 1.0000000 0.5000000 0.3750000
[5,] 0.6666667 0.5000000 0.5714286 0.5000000 1.0000000 0.3333333
[6,] 0.6666667 0.6250000 0.2857143 0.3750000 0.3333333 1.0000000
```

**Data**

```
> dput(a)
structure(c(0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, NA, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L,
1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, NA, NA), .Dim = c(6L, 
10L))
```

Comment: This looks close to what I need! I just included the result I am aiming for in the question. Thanks!

Comment: @snitsova You are welcome. Could you explain a bit why `b[2,1]` is `5/9`? How do the `5` and `9` come? I have no idea about the logic behind

Comment: `b[2,1]` is `5/9` because members of parliament 2 and 1 voted the same way -- either both said No (0,0) or both said Yes (1,1) -- 5 times and the number of issues members of parliament 2 and 1 both voted on, irrespective of whether they both said Yes or No or differed in their vote, is 9 (the NA in `a[2,1]` indicates that member of parliament 2 did not vote on issue 1). Does this make sense?

Comment: @snitsova Yes, now it seems clear to me. Please check out my update

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using a for loop.

```
b <- matrix(nrow=6, ncol=6)

for (i in 1:nrow(a)) {
for (j in 1:nrow(a)) {
  b[j, i] <- length(which(a[i,] == a[j,]))/
    (length(a[i,]) -
       length(union(which(is.na(a[i, ])), which(is.na(a[j, ])))))
}
}
```